# Optimize Firebase queries when a lot of leaves

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a 3000+ leaves under one node. I need to fetch value1,value2,value3, value4 for a query, but it seems to get slow due to a lot of leaves. How do I achieve it faster and optimize this case?

I have tried this Firebase optimization [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize) but could not derive a solution for this case.

Structure:

```
root
   |-id1
   |-id2
   .
   .
   |-idn
      |-key1:value1
      |-key2:value2
      .
      .
      |-key10: value10
   |-idn+1
   .
   .
   .
   |-id3000
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the value is an object then indexing the query should be the first step

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I'm not sure how much that will optimize? Say I have 20,000 leaves in this instead of 3,000, will this structure good enough (in terms of speed)? @cutiko

Comment: Given how broad you've written the question, any answer is going to be equally broad. For example: if you have too much many nested nodes and that slows down the query, you should reduce the nesting, or request less data. Most of this is covered in the [documentation on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data). To get a more concrete answer, show more concretely what the problem is. For example: show a snippet of the actual JSON, tell us what the size of the data is that you're reading, how much time it takes, what bandwidth you're testing on, etc.